# Bandwidth usage in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

Our compagny has a central Sql Server Database which is connected to many applications (Web, Backend/Frontend services, backoffice, ..) This database is hosted in a small country (for taxing advantages) where bandwidth is expensive.

Is there any way to have a detailed view of bandwidth usage ? such as how bytes are sent per application, per stored procedure, per login...

I want to monitor this at Sql Server because I can not do this at client side (too many clients and it is not suitable to alter client code for that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can snap [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) which will give you the net IO metrics for any given connection. The associated [`sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) will identify the connection client (host, application). Since you need aggregated history and the view gives moment in time snapshot you will have to do the usual transformations to convert moment-in-time to aggregate history.

Comment: it is possible to have a similar thing for sp exec ? Because in fact, I have only one major connection ...

Comment: no. is not because is not captured, is simply because the concept you ask for does not exists. You can infer some from the execution statistics [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) by assuming that a higher number of `total_rows` implies more network writes.